# I want to use "once per bar" feature in Strategy inputs as in Indicator. What should I do?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, strategy-pattern, closest, candlestick-chart

I want to use "once per bar" feature in Strategy inputs as in Indicator. What should I do?

I want the strategy to be traded immediately as in the indicator without waiting for the candle to close when the conditions are met .  Thanks..

I don't want it to wait for the candle to close. It should be processed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Use [process_orders_on_close](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy)

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", process_orders_on_close = true)
```

Comment: Yes for "EXİT" but not working for "OPEN" .